# C# How to know which elements of a list are substrings of a string?

Tags: c#, string, list, substring

If I have a list of string like

```
var MyList = new List<string>
{
    "substring1", "substring2", "substring3", "substring4", "substring5"
};
```

is there any efficient way to determine which elements of that list are contained in the following string

"substring1 is the substring2 document that was processed electronically"

In this case the result should be

```
var MySubList = new List<string>
{
    "substring1", "substring2"
};
```

Comment: Aho–Corasick algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20the%20Aho,%22)%20within%20an%20input%20text.)

Comment: `var`'d variables shouldn't be PascalCase

Comment: Are you matching whole words, or should `hello asubstring1z world` match too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use LINQ `Where` to query, for every substring, whether the large string `Contains` the substring:

```
var MyList = new List<string>
{
    "substring1", "substring2", "substring3", "substring4", "substring5"
};

var Text = "substring1 is the substring2 document that was processed electronically";

var output = MyList.Where(x => Text.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the `Text` by whitespaces
2. Sort the words alphabetically
3. Create a unique list from that

```
var words = Text.Split(" ").OrderBy(word => word).Distinct().ToList();
```

4. Create an accumulator collection for the matches
5. Create two index variables (one for the `words`, one for the `patterns`)

```
List<string> matches = new();
int patternIdx = 0, wordIdx = 0;
```

6. Iterate through the lists until you reach one of the collections' end

```
while(patternIdx < patterns.Count && wordIdx < words.Count)
{

}
```

7. Perform a string comparison
8. Advance index variable(s) based on the comparison result

```
int comparison = string.Compare(patterns[patternIdx],words[wordIdx]);
switch(comparison)
{
    case > 0: wordIdx++; break;
    case < 0: patternIdx++; break;
    default: 
    {
        matches.Add(patterns[patternIdx]); 
        wordIdx++;
        patternIdx++;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here I've used C# 9 new feature [switch + pattern matching](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2021/02/25/c-9-0-pattern-matching-in-switch-expressions/).
If you can't use C# 9 then a `if ... else if .. else` block would be fine as well.

---

For the sake of completeness here is the whole code

```
var Text = "substring1 is the substring2 document that was processed electronically";
var words = Text.Split(" ").OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
var patterns = new List<string> {  "substring1", "substring2", "substring3", "substring4", "substring5" };

List<string> matches = new();
int patternIdx = 0, wordIdx = 0;
while(patternIdx < patterns.Count && wordIdx < words.Count)
{
    int comparison = string.Compare(patterns[patternIdx], words[wordIdx]);
    switch(comparison)
    {
        case > 0: wordIdx++; break;
        case < 0: patternIdx++; break;
        default: 
        {
            matches.Add(patterns[patternIdx]); 
            wordIdx++;
            patternIdx++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Dotnetfiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8neX60)

Comment: If I change the text to `"substring1 is the substring2, document that was processed electronically"` then this code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Enigmativity Did you just add a comma after `substring2`?

Comment: @Enigmativity In that case all you need to do is to replace `Split("")` call to `Split(' ', ',')`

Comment: I could have added any character after the substring.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well, it depends what is the exact requirement from the OP for this situation.

Comment: It was a poor specification from the OP. I took it as literally a substring.